# Update free space amount displayed in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, windows-shell

how to update free space amount displayed in Windows Explorer for a drive ?

Suppose Windows Explorer is opened and some files are deleted programmatically.
Windows Explorer will not be refreshed to show the new free space available.

So, I tried to use `SHChangeNotify` like this (Delphi code) :

```
ws := 'C:\';
SHChangeNotify (SHCNE_FREESPACE, SHCNF_PATH, PWideChar(ws), nil);
```

but it doesn't update values reported in "Windows Explorer".

Please help.

Comment: How are you deleting the file? `DeleteFile`, or moving it to the recycle bin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Delphi 7, then `SHCNF_PATH` will map to the ANSI version, `SHCNF_PATHA`. In which case passing `PWideChar` is wrong. Write it like this:

```
var
  Drive: string;
....
Drive := 'C:\';
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_FREESPACE, SHCNF_PATH, PChar(Drive), nil);
```

Or, if you prefer to use the Unicode version, then you need to use `SHCNF_PATHW`.

```
var
  Drive: WideString;
....
Drive := 'C:\';
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_FREESPACE, SHCNF_PATHW, PWideChar(Drive), nil);
```