# How to get notified when disk free space changes?

Tags: delphi, winapi, events, delphi-2009

I used this code but it doesn't work for `SHCNE_FREESPACE`, I don't receive any notification if I delete or copy files in the specified folder. Only if I use other flags I receive notifications.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ShlObj, ActiveX;

const

  SHCNRF_INTERRUPTLEVEL     = $0001;
  SHCNRF_SHELLLEVEL         = $0002;
  SHCNRF_RECURSIVEINTERRUPT = $1000;
  SHCNRF_NEWDELIVERY        = $8000;

type
  TSHChangeNotifyEntry = record
    pidl: PItemIdList;
    fRecursive: BOOL;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure OnNotifyEvent(var AMessage:TMessage); message WM_USER;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Hand: THandle;

function SHChangeNotifyRegister(OwnerHwnd:HWND; fSources:Integer; fEvents:DWord; wMsg:UINT;
         cEntries:Integer; var pshcne:TSHChangeNotifyEntry):ULONG; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll';

function SHChangeNotifyDeregister(ulID:ULONG):BOOL; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Desktop:IShellFolder;
    pidl:PItemIdList;
    Path:String;
    Eaten,attr,Events,Sources:DWord;
    cnPIDL:TSHChangeNotifyEntry;
begin
 if Succeeded(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop)) then begin
  Path:='D:\Test';
  if Succeeded(Desktop.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PWideChar(Path), Eaten, pidl, attr)) then begin
   Caption:=Path;
   cnPIDL.pidl:=pidl;
   cnPIDL.fRecursive:=true;
   Sources:=SHCNRF_INTERRUPTLEVEL or SHCNRF_SHELLLEVEL or SHCNRF_NEWDELIVERY or SHCNRF_RECURSIVEINTERRUPT;
   Events:=SHCNE_FREESPACE;
   Hand:=SHChangeNotifyRegister(Handle, Sources, Events, WM_USER, 1, cnPIDL);;
   CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
  end;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SHChangeNotifyDeregister(Hand);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnNotifyEvent(var AMessage: TMessage);
begin
 if AMessage.Msg = WM_USER then Caption:=Caption+' x';
end;

end.
```

Comment: What "other flags" do you mean specifically?

Comment: `SHCNE_DELETE` for example, and I get notified when I delete a file

Comment: I want to display HDD free space in my application all the time.

Comment: I mean, if a file is added, edited, moved, or deleted, all of those would affect the free space. If all you want to do is a constant display of free space, I suggest using a simple timer which fetches free space, for example every half second. If it's the system disk, for example, there will be TONS of activity at any given time.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the root of the drive ?

Comment: Also, your program will fail if the window is recreated. You should be using AllocateHWnd here.

Comment: I tried even with the drive root but still not get notified.

Comment: @TLama, If I include `SHCNE_INTERRUPT` I receive all the events, even rename event, but not a single FreeSpace event.

Comment: Then you're luckier than me. I haven't received `SHCNE_FREESPACE` yet (Windows 7 64-bit).

Comment: I'm just going to point this out again, is it really necessary to capture every single time the available space changes? On a system drive, this will change much faster than your UI will be able to display to the user, and depending on how you format the size (KB, MB, GB...) it could cause a flicker and the user wouldn't even be able to read it with it changing so quickly. I would resort to a timer for this task.

Comment: The available free space can be updated with a little delay but in the end it must be updated. The value displayed on the screen must be the real available free space on the disk. I don't want to check the free space every second and keep the thread busy.

Comment: My point is that in your case, you'll be updating it every 1/50th of a second, for example, more of a chance of keeping the thread busy. And it doesn't have to be every second, it could be every 3 seconds. And as David pointed out, your current code will break if the window is recreated, which means it's less likely to be updated. Long story short, you can't control how quickly a disk has these changes. Have you tried your code on a system drive yet?

Comment: I can't try it because I don't reveive any `SHCNE_FREESPACE` event.

Comment: Well yeah I mean but you got the rest of them working. Without testing though, I can only imagine that the C drive (with Windows) is going to be triggering this event hundreds of times faster than the D drive which you're currently testing. Think of how often Windows writes data, even when you're not doing anything. Registry, log files, downloading updates... all of that will contribute to very excessive activity. What I'm proposing is much easier and much lighter weight. You could even write a thread to do it if you're worried about performance.

Comment: @Jerry, no worries. That event seems not to be triggered by the Shell. It looks like only apps. can send it manually by the `SHChangeNotify` function. A reliable event combination seems to be `SHCNE_CREATE or SHCNE_DELETE or SHCNE_UPDATEITEM` for sources `SHCNRF_INTERRUPTLEVEL or SHCNRF_RECURSIVEINTERRUPT` for the drive root.

Comment: @Jerry, taking back, the `SHCNE_FREESPACE` event seems to be triggered (at least) by the Windows Explorer.

Comment: @TLama So in the rare event (but common on kiosks) that explorer.exe is not running, this may not work at all?

Comment: +1 after learning the connection between these events and Windows Explorer. It appears these events must be controlled by Windows Explorer, in which case if certain things happen outside of Explorer, they may not be triggered.

Comment: @Jerry, yes, that seems to be true from what I observed. The `SHCNE_FREESPACE` event never fired for changes outside the Windows Explorer on my system. So I wouldn't suggest it for disk space change monitoring.

Comment: @TLama Looks like RRUZ deleted his answer, I suggest you write one up since you've been testing this case.

Comment: Ok, I run some tests And it seems which the `SHCNE_FREESPACE` notification only is received when the changes are made in the Windows explorer, but since  you are interested on this kind of changes what about using the  `FindFirstChangeNotification` method?

Comment: maybe worth checking if value of SHCNE_FREESPACE constant is correct ? also some values seem to be different between ANSI and UNICODE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929923

Comment: @Arioch, it has nothing to do with that issue (here is used item ID list, not a path). The problem here is the event itself. It doesn't fire for non Explorer disk space changes. I'd second RRUZ here, the mentioned change notifications seems to be the right way to go.

Comment: Yes, but `FindFirstChangeNotification` doesn't have a notification for free space changes.

Comment: @Marus, I think you can filter for `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE` recursively for a drive root. If the drive root changes its size, the drive's free space has changed.

Comment: I tried. That is only working if a file change it's size but not when I delete a file.

Comment: I must include `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` and `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` to get notified for every change in free space... but I will get the rename event too.

Comment: My two cents worth is that this is bananas.  This could be a huge overhead on some systems.  And what for.  Storage is so cheap.  Why would even bother to know what is happening.  Except for once a day maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my attempt (written in Delphi 2009):

```
unit DiskSpace;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Classes, ShlObj;

type
  PLONG = ^LONG;
  LONG = LongInt;

  TSpaceChangeEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const DiskFree, DiskTotal: Int64) of object;

  TDiskSpace = class
  strict private
    FDiskRoot: string;
    FDiskFree: Int64;
    FDiskTotal: Int64;
    FWndHandle: HWND;
    FNotifierID: ULONG;
    FOnSpaceChange: TSpaceChangeEvent;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); virtual;
    procedure DoSpaceChange(const DiskFree, DiskTotal: Int64); virtual;
  public
    constructor Create(Drive: Char); virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property DiskRoot: string read FDiskRoot;
    property DiskFree: Int64 read FDiskFree;
    property DiskTotal: Int64 read FDiskTotal;
    property OnSpaceChange: TSpaceChangeEvent read FOnSpaceChange write FOnSpaceChange;
  end;

implementation

const
  shell32 = 'shell32.dll';

  SHCNRF_InterruptLevel = $0001;
  SHCNRF_ShellLevel = $0002;
  SHCNRF_RecursiveInterrupt = $1000;
  SHCNRF_NewDelivery = $8000;

  WM_SHELL_ITEM_NOTIFY = WM_USER + 666;

type
  PSHChangeNotifyEntry = ^TSHChangeNotifyEntry;
  TSHChangeNotifyEntry = record
    pidl: PItemIDList;
    fRecursive: BOOL;
  end;

procedure ILFree(pidl: PItemIDList); stdcall;
  external shell32 name 'ILFree';
function ILCreateFromPath(pszPath: PWideChar): PItemIDList; stdcall;
  external shell32 name 'ILCreateFromPathW';
function SHChangeNotifyRegister(hwnd: HWND; fSources: Integer; fEvents: LONG; wMsg: UINT;
  cEntries: Integer; pshcne: PSHChangeNotifyEntry): ULONG; stdcall;
  external shell32 name 'SHChangeNotifyRegister';
function SHChangeNotifyDeregister(ulID: ULONG): BOOL; stdcall;
  external shell32 name 'SHChangeNotifyDeregister';

{ TDiskSpace }

constructor TDiskSpace.Create(Drive: Char);
var
  NotifyEntry: TSHChangeNotifyEntry;
begin
  FDiskRoot := Drive + ':\';
  FWndHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);

  NotifyEntry.pidl := ILCreateFromPath(PWideChar(FDiskRoot));
  try
    NotifyEntry.fRecursive := True;
    FNotifierID := SHChangeNotifyRegister(
      FWndHandle,
      SHCNRF_ShellLevel or SHCNRF_InterruptLevel or SHCNRF_RecursiveInterrupt,
      SHCNE_CREATE or SHCNE_DELETE or SHCNE_UPDATEITEM,
      WM_SHELL_ITEM_NOTIFY,
      1,
      @NotifyEntry);
  finally
    ILFree(NotifyEntry.pidl);
  end;
end;

destructor TDiskSpace.Destroy;
begin
  if FNotifierID <> 0 then
    SHChangeNotifyDeregister(FNotifierID);
  if FWndHandle <> 0 then
    DeallocateHWnd(FWndHandle);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDiskSpace.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  NewFree: Int64;
  NewTotal: Int64;
begin
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_SHELL_ITEM_NOTIFY) then
  begin
    if GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(PChar(FDiskRoot), NewFree, NewTotal, nil) then
    begin
      if (FDiskFree <> NewFree) or (FDiskTotal <> NewTotal) then
      begin
        FDiskFree := NewFree;
        FDiskTotal := NewTotal;
        DoSpaceChange(FDiskFree, FDiskTotal);
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      FDiskFree := -1;
      FDiskTotal := -1;
    end;
  end
  else
    Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FWndHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
end;

procedure TDiskSpace.DoSpaceChange(const DiskFree, DiskTotal: Int64);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnSpaceChange) then
    FOnSpaceChange(Self, DiskFree, DiskTotal);
end;

end.
```

And a possible usage:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDiskSpace: TDiskSpace;
    procedure DiskSpaceChange(Sender: TObject; const DiskFree, DiskTotal: Int64);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDiskSpace := TDiskSpace.Create('C');
  FDiskSpace.OnSpaceChange := DiskSpaceChange;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDiskSpace.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.DiskSpaceChange(Sender: TObject; const DiskFree, DiskTotal: Int64);
begin
  Caption := Format('%d/%d B', [DiskFree, DiskTotal]);
end;
```

Comment: But I think that `FindFirstChangeNotification` is better way.

Comment: You're welcome! But still I think that `SHChangeNotifyRegister` is cleaner here.

Comment: I think you are referring to `FindFirstChangeNotification` (like you said in the first comment), but no, `SHChangeNotifyRegister` is good too. I've tested it further today and I found that `SHCNE_UPDATEDIR` must be included too because in its documentation says that, for performance reasons, multiple `SHCNE_UPDATEITEM` notifications can be combined into a single `SHCNE_UPDATEDIR` notification. I also think that it's good to include `SHCNE_RMDIR`. And there is no need to include `SHCNRF_SHELLLEVEL` in `fSources`.

Comment: And other good thing that can be done is to set a timer on the first `WM_SHELL_ITEM_NOTIFY` and not processing further messages until the time elapses. I saw that if i delete 20 files I get 20 messages at once, but if I put a timer I will get only one notification.

Comment: I was wrong, `SHCNRF_SHELLLEVEL` must be included in fSources.

Comment: ...to receive notifications from Shell (e.g. Windows Explorer). And yes, that was a typo, sorry for that :)